# Retrieve whole string from a javascript value variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to save a large string as a value in an javascript variable, the problem is that can only save the first word of the string in the javascript variable, my source code is the following :

The JS function is called when a button is clicked by the user, then the value of the button("The value of the variable is the large string") is stored in the javascript variable, and then is been displayed in an html form. The source code of the html form is the following:

```js
var input; //prepare var to save large string
    $(function() {
     // contact form animations
     $('button[id="contactbutton"]').click(function() {
     input = $(this).val(); //set var input to value of the pressed button
       document.getElementById("someInput").value = input;
        console.log('input : ' + input);
        $('#contactForm').fadeToggle();
      })
      $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $("#contactForm");
    
        if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            container.fadeOut();
          
        }
      });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contactForm" >
                      <p><h4><i>First Choose the clients and then the file which will be uploaded in order to proced</i></h4></2>
                      <hr>
                      <input type="text" id="someInput" name="someInput" readonly></input>
                      <hr>
                      </div>
```

The buttons are displayed in an html table, the table drags the data using mysql queries and display them in the website. Then an addition column is created consisting only of buttons, each button is given a different value, the source code of the table is the following:

```
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root",'');
   if(!$con){

   die("Cannot Connect" . mysql_error());

   }
  mysql_select_db("client_app",$con);
  $get_notifications= "SELECT * FROM `notifications history` ";
  $notifications = mysql_query($get_notifications,$con);

   echo "<table class=table table-condensed>
   <thead>
   <tr>   
   <th>Recipient</th>
   <th>Title</th>
   <th>Message</th>
   <th>Time Sended</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>";
   while($record = mysql_fetch_array($notifications)){
    echo "<action=usersfiles.php method=post>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$record['recipient']." </td>";
    echo "<td>".$record['title']." </td>";
      echo "<td>"."<button   value=".$record['content']." id=contactbutton>Content</button>"." </td>";
    echo "<td>".$record['received']." </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";

     }

echo "</table>";     
mysql_close();
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Can you create a snippet (click `<>`) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Please post relevant HTML also. Also, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also post the html form thats been called when the button is pressed

Comment: Where is the html for the button ? i made a simple example and your code works. see here > http://jsfiddle.net/q1ft25pn/24/ Also do not post code separately , instead create a StackOverflow code snippet ( `<>` button in toolbar  when editing a question/answer )

Comment: can you share the output html ( including the button and its value )  ?